# Is there a reason why passing objects to intents are not straight forward?

Tags: android

Why is that the object has to be serialized or be Parcelable in order to be passed to an Intent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intents can be sent between processes, so cannot contain Object:s limited to the current JVM.

Comment: Makes absolute sense, but is there a better way to pass objects to an activity when they are in the same VM ?

Comment: There are alternatives which may be better - see "How do I pass data between Activities/Services within a single application?" at http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html#3